# Mongoose - don't allow documents to have identical arrays

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to create a database schema where a document cannot have an array that is identical to that of another document. So, say I have the schema `conversations`:

```
var ConversationSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    participants: {
        type: [{
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        }]
    }
});
```

Now if I create two conversations with the same participants, how can I validate this so that the second one will fail, but the third will not?

```
var conversation1 = new Conversation({
    name: "Hello",
    participants: ['12345', '09876']
});

var conversation2 = new Conversation({
    name: "World",
    participants: ['12345', '09876']
});

var conversation3 = new Conversation({
    name: "Group chat",
    participants: ['12345', '09876', '13579']
});

conversation1.save(); // Valid
conversation2.save(); // Invalid - conversation already exists
conversation3.save(); // Valid
```

Comment: This seems like a business logic not schema validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could use some custom *Mongoose* validation before saving your data.
But this is not really a schema thing, as Kevin said in his comment, since you will need to make a database query to compare already existing array with the new one.
Something like this (not tested):

```
function checkArray(arr) {
// here make a call to the db to compare existing array with arr
}

var ConversationSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    participants: {
        type: [{
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User',
            validate: checkArray
        }]
    }
});
```

No better idea for now.

Comment: That kinda sucks, but I can do it this way I suppose. Thanks